# Instance Name as Parameter

Tags: function, actionscript, parameters

I have a drag/drop project in AS 3.0 and I need help about sending instance names as parameters.

Here is my code (works fine):

```
item1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag);
item2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, f2_ClickToDrag);
item3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, f3_ClickToDrag);
item4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, f4_ClickToDrag);

function fl_ClickToDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    item1.startDrag();
}
function f2_ClickToDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    item2.startDrag();
}
function f3_ClickToDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    item3.startDrag();
}
function f4_ClickToDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    item4.startDrag();
}
```

Can I get something like:

```
function all_ClickToDrag(event:MouseEvent, item:I don't know what to write):void
{
    item.startDrag();
}
```

How can I write something like this, how can I call it? For example my functions has parameter "event" and still I'm calling it without any parameter:

```
item1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag);
```

What if I want to send a second parameter. I hope you help me.

Note: I can send MovieClip names as parameters too but sending Instance Names will be too much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the target propery of the event

```
var itemSource:Object=event.target;
```

To send more information with events you need to create custom events and Event classes and dispatch them.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Editor didn't show .startDrag option but I wrote it and it worked.

var itemSource:Object=event.target; itemSource.startDrag();

I hope this is the right use. If not, still waiting for your help. Thanks again.